# resize partition of / on ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

Currently i am running Ubuntu server 12.04. works great.. till today i realize i flawed my partition setup and set / to a 6gb partition, and /home to a 30gb partition on the same drive..

```
here is my current table
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       5.5G  4.4G  912M  83% /
udev            741M  4.0K  741M   1% /dev
tmpfs           150M  416K  150M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            750M     0  750M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda5        33G  176M   31G   1% /home
```

i'm pretty sure my swap file resides between the 2..

my question is how can i resize this so / can have more room, whilst /home has less..

help?

Comment: Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    11711384     5855661   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        11711446    80019764    34154159+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5        11711448    80019764    34154158+  83  Linux

Comment: Did the answers of the possible duplicate question provide any help?